# Leon-Aubert Violin Year?

Tags: violin

How do I know when my Leon-Aubert violin was made? There is no name but there is a serial number. However, I cannot find any information about it anywhere.  I am sure I am not Googling it correctly but don't know how to look it up.

My parents bought it used in 1987, so it has some age on it.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I meant it does not have a date in there.  It clearly says Leon-Aubert.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't find it already, but you can learn from the current violin makers. They can recognize it by the quality of what tree, for example, or painting it, and see a lot of details that we don’t see. So the only way I can advise, because on the Internet you will not find!